# Thunderbird: Two email accounts using the same SMTP server

Tags: email, thunderbird, smtp

This is a recent problem, which I did not have until the past month.

I have two different emails from the same Spectrum account, one for personal and one for business. They both use the same SMTP server.

When I send from one account, I get an error that the email has to be sent from the same email address I logged in with. I checked the SMTP server for that email address and it changed to the other one. I was able to keep each SMTP server, giving them  different names and associate each email account with the same server this way.

Now Thunderbird sees them as being the same and I can't send the email without changing the SMTP server email address all the time. I am using the most recent version of Thunderbird.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do that by having two identities in the
same account, each with its own SMTP server.

This is the procedure as I see it:

- Add an additional SMTP server:

  - Go to Account Settings
  - At the bottom of the left pane click on "Outgoing Server (SMTP)".
  - Click the "Add..." button.
  - Insert the second SMTP server information and click OK.
- To use this newly added SMTP server for any other identity:

  - In Account Settings, click on the account name in the left pane,
    whose identities you want to change
  - Press "Manage Identities..."
  - Select the identity that you want to change, and press "Edit..."
  - Choose the SMTP server you want to use from the
    "Outgoing Server (SMTP)" pull-down list.

Comment: I already did this.   The problem is that the mail server is the same, even though I named them differently.

Comment: This shouldn't happen.

Comment: They fixed the problem yesterday or today

Comment: This means that the above configuration works after some changes were done outside of your computer?